# Как отобразить комментарии из обсуждений ВК на сайт WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, vkontakte-api

Народ, всем привет, нужно вывести комментарии из темы обсуждений (в группе в ВК куча отзывов) ВК на сайт. В инете нашёл несколько способов: все они сводятся к VK API (https://vk.com/dev/board.getComments), т.к. специализированного виджета для подобных целей нет. Создал следующий запрос:

```
<?php

$request_params = [
'group_id' => '92457343',
'topic_id' => '32000957',
'need_likes' => 1,
'offset' => 0,
'count' => 100,
'extended' => 1,
'sort' => 'desc',
'version' => 5.87,
'access_token' => '***'

];

$url = "https://api.vk.com/method/board.getComments?" . http_build_query($request_params);

$result = file_get_contents($url);
echo $result;

?>
```

Всё выводит (получил данные в формате JSON), а теперь каким образом полученные данные вывести на страницу сайта Word Press’a?

Comment: А в чем у вас проблема? Разобрать json?

Comment: Проблема с выводом полученных данных на страницу сайта) попытался сделать через PHP Snippets, и вывод с помощью short code, но не вышло. Я банально нуб, перерыл кучу инфы, но конкретного по данной теме не нашёл. Может ткнете носом, или хотя бы посоветовать что почитать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через шорткод

Добавь в фаил `wp-content/themes/название шаблона/functions.php`

```
function get_comments_vk( $atts ) {
  $request_params = [
  'group_id' => '92457343',
  'topic_id' => '32000957',
  'need_likes' => 1,
  'offset' => 0,
  'count' => 100,
  'extended' => 1,
  'sort' => 'desc',
  'version' => 5.87,
  'access_token' => '***'

  ];

  $url = "https://api.vk.com/method/board.getComments?" . http_build_query($request_params);

  $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
  $response = $result->response;
  $rez = '';
  foreach ($response->comments as $value) {
    $rez .= 'id отправителя: '.$value->from_id.'<br>';
    $rez .= 'Текст: '.$value->text.'<br><br>';
  }
  return $rez;
}
add_shortcode( 'get_comments_vk', 'get_comments_vk' );
```

И выводи в самом шаблон `[get_comments_vk]`